# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/pdo_sqlite.so' with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sqlite, php-7.1

I'm getting this warning when running the phpunit test suite in Jenkins pipeline.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/pdo_sqlite.so' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/pdo_sqlite.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name in Unknown on line 0
```

However this warning is not thrown when running the test suite directly in terminal.

I have PHP 7.1 in my system and this is the only PHP version I have installed. `php7.1-sqlite3` is installed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you solve this issue? Is the answer below the Accepted Answer?

Comment: @nterms did you solved this issue?

Comment: @GligorFlorin no, I'm sorry. I just gave it up

Answer (score 10):

As far as I have found out, there is a faulty file in `/usr/local/lib` called `libsqlite3.so.0` which points to `libsqlite3.so.0.8.6`. I renamed the file in case it was needed for something. With the command:

`cd /usr/local/lib`
`sudo mv libsqlite3.so.0 ./libsqlite3.so.0.back`

But you can also delete it:
`rm libsqlite3.so.0`

The thread that lead me to the answer: [link](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1505101)

This solved my problems, and I hope they solve yours as well :)

Comment: In my case there is nothing in that directory. I also looked at /usr/lib/php/modules/sqlite3.so which also doesn't have the .so file I need. So I'm guessing I just need to find it and manually install it. Unless there's a better way.

Comment: Three years later I havn't found anything to suggest ther is :/

Answer (score 5):

I had this same issue with PHP 7.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Running the following fixed the issue for me:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.1-sqlite3
```

Comment: Tried this (PHP 7.1, Ubuntu 18.04), didn't solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you built SQLite from source? If yes, enable Column metadata and recompile with

```
CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA=1" ./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Have fun using the cutting edge SQLite.

Reference - https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_column_metadata